# Jquery Tools - multiple tooltips, different images

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I've made some tooltips using JQuery Tools, which works fine but I want a second tooltip on the same page with a different image, and I don't know how. Here is my code:

```
<span id="tip">
<img src="images/info20.png" title="(popup text)" />
</span></td>

$(function() {  
$("#tip img[title]").tooltip({position: "top right", offset:[0,-25]});
});

.tooltip {
display:none;
font-family: arial;
background: url(../images/purple.png);
font-size:11px;
height:70px;
width:160px;
padding:25px;
color:#fff;
```

}

I thought I should just be able to make one the same as this but change "tooltip" to "tooltip2" and select a different image in the CSS but this doesn't work. Can anyone help? Unfortunately the forums on JQuery Tools seem to be broken so I can't get any help there.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with jqueryTools because in the manual there is no option, or I haven't found it where you could specify an optional background for a tooltip only !

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it, but it can probably be improved:

```
<span id="tip" class="puprle">
<img src="images/info20.png" title="(popup text)" />
</span>

<span id="tip" class="green">
<img src="images/info21.png" title="(popup text 2)" />
</span>


$(function() {  
  $("#tip.purple img[title]").tooltip({
    position: "top right",
    offset:[0,-25],
    tipClass:'tooltipPurple'
  });
  $("#tip.green img[title]").tooltip({
    position: "top right",
    offset:[0,-25],
    tipClass:'tooltipGreen'
  });
});

.tooltipPurple {
    display:none;
    font-family: arial;
    background: url(../images/purple.png);
    font-size:11px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#fff; 
}

.tooltipGreen {
    display:none;
    font-family: arial;
    background: url(../images/green.png);
    font-size:11px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#fff; 
}
```